# python manage.py migrate --fake-initial errors on initial migration

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have a new Django app pointing to an existing django database and so I want to skip some initial migrations. However, even running `fake-initial` still tries to run the initial migrations:

> raise InconsistentMigrationHistory(
> django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration donate.0001_initial is applied before its dependency campaign.0003_remove_medicalcenter_npi_num_and_more on database 'default'.

What's the point of `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial` then??